# placement of an image in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to place an image inside a tikzpicture. The problem is the cloud is around the center of the image, so the face of the image is not visible.

```
  \node[cloud, draw,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=12, aspect=1.,inner sep=2cm,fill overzoom
  image=images/thethinker2] at (0,-7){};
```

How I can align my image w.r.t. the cloud?

**Update**:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}
\RequirePackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Hello}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
  \node[circle,inner sep=1cm,fill overzoom image=images/thethinker_small] (A) {};   
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: image used]

Comment: Could you provide us an MWE ?

Comment: Could you put an image of what you want ?

Comment: I want the face of the sculpture in the node visible.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fill overzoom image*={<graphic options>}{<filename>}` instead (note the `*`), and use that to trim the lower part of the image. For example with,

```
fill overzoom image*={clip,trim=0 3cm 0 0}{example-image-10x16}
```

3cm will be cut away from the bottom of the image. The four values supplied to `trim` is for the left, bottom, right, and top, respectively.

Strictly speaking might be easier to crop the image in an image editor first though.

Another option would be to use `path picture` instead of `fill overzoom image`. Place the image in a `node` in the `path picture`, and adjust the coordinates of the node to move the image around.

Quick example:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
  \node[circle,inner sep=1cm,fill overzoom image=example-image-10x16] (A) {};   
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
  \node[circle,inner sep=1cm,fill overzoom image*={clip,trim=0 3cm 0 0}{example-image-10x16}] (A) {};   
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
  \node[circle,draw,inner sep=1cm,path picture={
   % adjust (2,-2.5) to move image around
   \node at (2,-2.5) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-10x16}};
    }
  ] (A) {};   
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```